# Launch python script with abaqus command

Tags: python, abaqus

I have a command file (.cmd) which I use to launch Abaqus command line windows.
Then, I use the command 'abaqus python test.py' to launch python command inside Abaqus.

Now, I would like to use a python script to do that.
I try something like this but doesn't work. Someone know the trick ?

Thanks !!

```
import subprocess

AbaqusPath=r"C:\Abaqus\script\abaqus.cmd"
args= AbaqusPath + "-abaqus python test.py"
subprocess.call(args)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do ? run a script that does stuff in CAE or run a script that does some analysis etc (but no CAE tasks)  ?

Comment: A script that run analysis (read odb file) so no CAE tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using .cmd-file:

This way might work with cmd file:

```
abaqusPath = "C:\\Abaqus\\script\\abaqus.cmd /C"
args = AbaqusPath + "abaqus python test.py"
subprocess.call(args)
```

Flag /C is needed to run command and then terminate.

### Easiest way:

Just add the folder with abaqus commands (typical path C:\Abaqus\Commands) into the PATH variable of the system. This will give the access to commands like abaqus, abq6141 etc. in cmd directly.

When just use the following in your script:

```
subprocess.call("abaqus python test.py")
```

### Using .bat-file:

If the configuration of PATH variable is impossible and the first way does not work, .bat-files from abaqus can be used as follows:

```
abaqusPath = "C:\\Abaqus\\Commands\\abaqus.bat "
args = AbaqusPath + "python test.py"
subprocess.call(args)
```

Comment: Could I get the return of subprocess call ? To know if something went wrong ?

Comment: Yes, as I understand all of them return the value of exit. Just assign it to some variable, for instance a = subprocess.call(). Then you can check if it is non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

I've never had any success using just string arguments for subprocess functions.

I would try it this way:

```
import subprocess

abaqus_path = r"C:\Abaqus\script\abaqus.cmd"
subprocess.call([abaqus_path, '-abaqus', 'python', 'test.py'])
```